# Fstream access as private member

Tags: c++, inheritance, fstream

**File class**

```
class File
{
private:
    fstream dataFile;

public:
    File();
};

File::File()
{
    dataFile.open("Morse.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if(dataFile.fail())
        cout << "File could not be opened.\n";
    else
        cout << "File opened successfully!\n";
}
```

**Decoder class**

```
class Decoder: public File
{
private:
    char line;

public:
    void getLine();
};

void Decoder::getLine()
{
    while(dataFile.get(line))
    {
       cout << line;
    }
}
```

2 Questions:

1. Does `dataFile` contain the `Morse.bin` contents? The `file opened successfully` message shows up, but I just want to make sure.
2. I want to read a character by character from in the `Decoder` class. The issue I am having is accessing the `dataFile` from the `Decoder` class. I tried creating a accessor function for the `dataFile` but it won't allow me to access it. The error messages is that `File::dataFile is inaccessible`. Which make sense because it is private. However, if I can't create a accessor function which would return `dataFile`, how do I get a hold of `dataFile` in order the manipulate it?

Comment: You could add **dataFile** in protected  or you could define `Decoder` as **friend class**.You have second option but its too silly normally **not recommended**

Answer (score 0):

1. Not yet. You haven't read from it.
2. Make `dataFile` protected, or provide an accessor to it from `File`.

   ```
   class File
   {
   protected:
       fstream dataFile;

   public:
       File();
   };

   File::File()
   {
       dataFile.open("Morse.bin", ios::in | ios::binary);
       if(dataFile.fail())
           cout << "File could not be opened.\n";
       else
           cout << "File opened successfully!\n";
   }
   ```

Comment: `fstream getDataFile() {return dataFile;}` gives me an error that `dataFile` is inaccessible.

Comment: @Bryan Are you adding that in the `Decoder` class? If so you need to put it in the `File` class. A private member can only be accessed in the class in which it was declared. Not even inheriting classes can access it.

Comment: I am adding it to the public section of file